# Alternative for COALESCE when all its parameters is null

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I am developing a web application (java-maven project) and there is a problem with the query I use. The UI of my web app has 2 search fields: `PTT` and `ID`.
The user needs to fill at least one of the fields to make a search. So both fields are nullable but not at the same time.
Before, I had only one field: `PTR` and it was showing a result array of size 52. (also getting the same number if
I execute `select * from users where ptr='smthing'` ). After that I added `ID` field and updated my query as below:

I execute this query in my webservice:

```
String query= "SELECT t.ptr, t.id ";
        query+= "FROM users t ";
        query+= "WHERE t.ptr = COALESCE(?, t.ptr) AND " ;
        query+= "t.id = COALESCE(?, t.id) ";
```

and set the fields with the help of Prepared Statement.

Now if the `ptr` field is filled, but `id` field is left blank (this can be null or empty string) on the UI and user makes a search, result array size becomes 30. I compared with database
and it does not fetch the rows where `ID` is null. So `coalesce` is not what I need when both of its parameters (?, t.ptr) is null.
How can I fix this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: what database ? oracle?

Comment: By the way, PL/SQL Developer is not an Oracle product and PL/SQL is not a query language.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is:

```
WHERE (t.ptr = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND 
      (t.id = ? OR ? IS NULL)
```

I would recommend using named parameters, so you don't have to pass them in twice.

Comment: Thank you :) A question: how do we set parameters for "?" here. In old version I set them like PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, obj.getPTT());  ps.setString(1, obj.getID()); I am asking this because now I get  "java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index"

Comment: @csel . . . This version has four parameters rather than two, so you need to include all four parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Check this statement:

```
String query= "SELECT t.ptr, t.id ";
query+= "FROM users t ";
query+= "WHERE (t.ptr = ? OR 1 = ?)" 
query+= " AND " ;
query+= "(t.id = ? OR 1 = ?)";
```

You see that for each of `t.id` and `t.ptr` there is a counterpart parameter. 
In total there will be 4 parameters.  
You say that **at least 1** of `t.id` or `t.ptr` has a valid value, so there are 2 cases:  
**[1]** `t.id` and `t.ptr` both have valid values. 
For both the counterpart parameters you pass `0` and the query becomes:
`"SELECT t.ptr, t.id FROM users t WHERE (t.ptr = valueptr OR 1 = 0) AND (t.id = valueid OR 1 = 0)"` 
In the WHERE part:  
`t.ptr = valueptr OR 1 = 0` is equivalent to `t.ptr = valueptr`, and 
`t.id = valueid OR 1 = 0` is equivalent to `t.id = valueid`, 
and the query finally becomes: 
`"SELECT t.ptr, t.id FROM users t WHERE t.ptr = valueptr AND t.id = valueid"` 
**[2]** from `t.id` or `t.ptr` only one has a valid value, let's say this is `t.ptr`. 
For the counterpart of `t.ptr` you pass `0`, for `t.id` you pass `-1` (or any other non existing value) and for the counterpart of `t.id` you pass `1` and the query becomes:
`"SELECT t.ptr, t.id FROM users t WHERE (t.ptr = valueptr OR 1 = 0) AND (t.id = -1 OR 1 = 1)"` 
In the WHERE part:  
`t.ptr = valueptr OR 1 = 0` is equivalent to `t.ptr = valueptr`, and 
`t.id = -1 OR 1 = 1` is equivalent to `true` because `1 = 1` is always `true`, 
 
and the query finally becomes: 
`"SELECT t.ptr, t.id FROM users t WHERE (t.ptr = valueptr OR 1 = 0)"` 
equivalent to: 
`"SELECT t.ptr, t.id FROM users t WHERE (t.ptr = valueptr)"` 
(In the case where only `t.id` has a valid value then you pass an invalid value for `t.ptr` and `1` for its counterpart and for the counterpart if `t.id` you pass `0`.) 
Maybe it seems complicated but it's working and it can be extended for more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has build function for this. But it's hard to understand how to use its.

`lnnvl(a = b)  = true  if (a != b ) or ( a = null ) or (b = null)`

in your case

```
WHERE lnnvl(t.ptr != ? ) AND lnnvl( t.id != ?)
```

[LNNVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions078.htm)

Comment: I have 2 questions. I used as you say now, it brings null fields which is one of the things I wanted but for example lets say ptr is entered as 'abcdef' and id is left blank it brings all the records with empty ptr and ptr='abcdef' from the DB. The second thing is that how can I use this with "BETWEEN" ? I want to add "query += "t.date BETWEEN COALESCE(?, t.date) AND COALESCE(?,t.date) AND "; " something like this with lnnvl.

Comment: ++ I think it is normal behavior of lnnvl to bring all the empty ptr values also. I just want to bring all the records with ptr value 'abcdef' (if the user submitted value for ptr field). But it was not bringing the records which has null ID and ptr='abcdef'